# Loop going through one number multiple times

Tags: matlab

I want for each numbas, the primlist less than or equal to numbas is given. My programming is doing the right thing for each numbas, but multiple times. Because of this I cannot save PPRIMMS as a vector called PLV.

eg if you see below the vector for numbas=69 is done more than once, I just want one numbas for every number up to 100. this is what is causing the demension mismatch in my program when trying to save the PPRIMS as PLV.

numbas =

```
69
```

PPRIMS =

Columns 1 through 13

```
 2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    31    37    41
```

Columns 14 through 26

```
43    47    53    59    61    67     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

numbas =

```
69
```

PPRIMS =

Columns 1 through 13

```
 2     3     5     7    11    13    17    19    23    29    31    37    41
```

Columns 14 through 26

```
43    47    53    59    61    67     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

code:

```
n=100;
primlist=2; % starting the prime number list


for numba=1:n;
   if mod(2+numba,primlist)~=0
      primlist=[primlist;2+numba]; %generating the prime number list
   end
end


for numbas=2:n
    prims=zeros(size(primlist));
    pprims=zeros(size(primlist));
    pow=prims;
    for k=1:10
        for i=1:length(primlist) % identifying each primes in the primlist
            if mod(numbas,primlist(i).^k)==0
                prims(i)=primlist(i); % sum of all the powers of prims, such that prims divide numbas
                pow(i)=k; % collecting the exponents of primes
            end

            if primlist(i)<=numbas
               pprims(i)=primlist(i);
            end
        end

numbas     
PPRIMS=pprims' % primes less than or equal to numbas   
PRIMS=prims'; % primes that divide numbas
POW=pow'; % highest prower of primes that divide numbas

PPV(numbas,:)=PRIMS; % saving prims
PVE(numbas,:)=POW; % Saving Pows
PLV(numbas.:)=PPRIMS % saving PPRIMS
numbas;


RVE=cumsum(PVE); % the cummulative sum of the exponents of PVE
%RVEC(numbas,:)=RVE

%numbas

%sigmafac=(prod(PPV.^(RVE(numbas)+1)-1))/((prod(PPV-1))) 
end



end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small typo in

```
PLV(numbas.:)
```

I think it should be

```
PLV(numbas,:)
```

Also, your inner loop

```
for k=1:10
```

is not close, and the rest of the code is inside this loop, that's why *numbas* is printed 10 times.

Comment: thanks you answer my question now it only does it once, i took it out of the inner loop, but still a demension mismatch. thanks anyways!

Comment: It's been a while that I used matlab but I do use octave which is pretty much the linux opensource version of matlab. Doing zeros(n) in octave gives you a nxn matrix of zeros. I don't know how is it in matlab though, but in octave you would do zeros(1,n) or zeros(n,1) if what you want is a row/column of zeros.

Comment: yes you can do that in matlab as well, I did zeros(size(primlist)) because I needed the size of the primlist which could be written as zeros(1,26) as well.